# Как присвоить элементу массива структур элемент массива (char). Язык Си

Tags: массивы, структуры, char

Имеется массив char "a+b*c"

и массив структур:

```
struct variables
  {   char vars;
      int value;
  };
  struct variables V[10];
```

Необходимо занести в char vars переменные a,b,c из массива-строки

при попытке сделать так:

```
&V[x].vars = str[q];
```

выдает ошибку "Lvalue required"

Использовать только стандартную библиотеку Си.

Comment: Не ясно, зачем Вы пытаетесь так что-то присвоить. Компилятор прав - не стоит пытаться брать адрес в такой ситуации. Вполне хватило бы простого `V[x].vars = str[q];`, если `str[q]` - это символ.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно, амперсанд был лишним.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
V[x].vars = str[q];
```

'&' был не нужен